# How to Split Strings based on conditions in R?

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I would like to split a single string into multiple strings by looking at the words 'split here' only if it exists between '>' & '<' and not remove any others characters except for the words 'split here'

```
text <- c("Don't split here > yes here split here and blah blah < again don't (anything could be here) split here >")
```

Expected output:

```
text[1] = "Don't split here > yes here "
text[2] = "and blah blah < again don't (anything could be here) split here >"
```

I tried

```
gsub(">(.*split here.*)<","", text)
```

but that doesn't seem to work. Can someone with regex exp. help me out here?

Comment: Can you check if my answer solves your question? If not, can you be a bit specific as to what doesn't work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Replace the required strings with \1 and then split on \1:

```
strsplit(gsub("(>[^<]+) split here ([^<]+<)", "\\1\1\\2", text), "\1")
## [[1]]
## [1] "Don't split here > yes here"             
## [2] "and blah blah < again don't split here >"
```

If the input is a character vector the output will be a list or if you want to flatten that just use `unlist(s)` where `s` is the result of the above line of code.

Comment: This is really clever, thanks for this. Unfortunately I am working with HTML code, so I have a bunch of '\n', '\b' etc. I won't be able to split '\n'. I'm sorry my question should have been a lot more clear

Comment: I have changed \n to \1 .

Answer (score 1):

You can use simple `strsplit` using this regex utilizing `\K` (using perl=TRUE) operator to give you the desired strings.

```
>[^>]*?\Ksplit here\s*(?=[^<]*<)
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/aRgQ2Z/2)**

**[R Code demo](https://rextester.com/TLCF8085)**

```
strsplit("Don't split here > yes here split here and blah blah < again don't (anything could be here) split here >", ">[^>]*?\\Ksplit here\\s*(?=[^<]*<)", perl=TRUE)
```

Prints,

```
[[1]]
[1] "Don't split here > yes here "                                     
[2] "and blah blah < again don't (anything could be here) split here >"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do something like this-

```
 > str_split(gsub(str_extract(text,"(?<=>).*?(?=\\<)"),gsub("split here","nsplit here",str_extract(text,"(?<=>).*?(?=\\<)")),text),"nsplit here")
```

**OUTPUT-**

```
[[1]]
[1] "Don't split here > yes here "                                      
    " and blah blah < again don't (anything could be here) split here >"
```